# blogdown project starts hugo on just opening project

Tags: r, blogdown

I am using RStudio 1.3.1093 and blogdown 0.21
Since I upgraded, whenever I open a project, it immediately runs

`blogdown:::preview_site(startup = TRUE)`

I have no ideas where the option to run this on opening the project is hidden.
I want to get rid of this. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. (Recommended) Install the development version of **blogdown**:

   ```r
   remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
   ```

   The behavior has been changed in the dev version, so there's nothing you need to do.
2. Set `options(blogdown.serve_site.startup = FALSE)` in your [global or local `.Rprofile`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html).